# How use php inside a jQuery file

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I've read about it but all the solutions doesn't help me.
I've already added this to my `.htaccess` file:

`<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">AddHandlerapplication/x-httpd-php .js</FilesMatch>`.

That's my javascript code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today'
      },
      defaultDate: "<?php echo $current ?>",
      editable: false,
```

But nothing appears then. I'd be grateful if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: @PatrickEvans [that's not true when there's only one line of code](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Comment: Why you wanna use PHP here? Just go `defaultDate: new Date(),`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thats not my whole actual code, its just a part of it. $current has just been defined before.

Comment: @connexo Later I want to print values from my database but i want first to learn how to print a php variable to do it then

Comment: You could use a twig template probably?

Comment: @AXAI It is defined in my head.php file so I think so

Comment: @connexo I don't completly understand what's a twig tempalte but if its useful i'm using notepad++

Comment: Can't you use a PHP file to produce the JS code? and then include it using `<script src="./myscript.php"></script>`

Comment: @MehdiBounya Are you sure it will work equally? EDIT: Tried and didn't work

Comment: No, I'm not, I tested it in Firefox Developers Beta edition and it worked with a text file, but you may want to test in other browsers or do some research.

Comment: The @MehdiBounya suggestion should work fine since JS files can have any extension as long as they are served with the proper header and referenced correctly in the script tag (the same for CSS files, images, etc. which can be also generated using this method). You should check this again.

Answer (score 1):

Set $current to javascript variable in php file and then include this js file.
page.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var currentDate = <?php echo $current; ?>;
</script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

In **script.js**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today'
      },
      defaultDate: currentDate,
      editable: false
});
```

Comment: how does this gonna help he is talking about php in `.js` file

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest an alternative way to generate your JS code.
By using a .php file, for example:
**myscript.php**

```
// Set the header type to JS
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

$value = 'Something here';

echo "alert('$value');";
```

and then just include it by using:

```
<script src="./myscript.php"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution is :

**1- creating file :**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
?>
var abc=0;
<?php echo "var babc='xyz'"?>;
```

**2- saving file by this format :**

```
filename.js.php
```

**3- adding rewrite rules to .htaccess**

```
RewriteRule "^(.*)\.php\.js$" "$1.js.php" [NC,NE,L,QSA]
```

**4-including .js file as :**

```
<script src="filename.php.js"></script>
```

the file name format need to be unique to be determined by rewrite rule, in this example i used :

```
FileName.php.js  for client side
FileName.js.php  for server side
```